# C# Moq verify publish event failed given custom event arguments

Tags: c#, events, moq, prism

So I have the following ViewModel:

```
using Prism.Commands;
using Prism.Events;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;
using TrackIt.Model;
using TrackIt.UI.Event;

namespace TrackIt.UI.ViewModel
{
    public class NavigationItemViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private string _displayMember;
        private IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;
        private string _detailViewModelName;

        public NavigationItemViewModel(int id,
            IEventAggregator eventAggregator,
            string detailViewModelName)
        {
            Id = id;
            _detailViewModelName = detailViewModelName;
            OpenDetailViewCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnOpenDetailViewExecute);
            _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        }
        public int Id { get; }

        public ICommand OpenDetailViewCommand { get; set; }

        private void OnOpenDetailViewExecute()
        {
            _eventAggregator.GetEvent<TestEvent>()
                        .Publish(Id);
            _eventAggregator.GetEvent<OpenDetailViewEvent>()
                        .Publish(
                new OpenDetailViewEventArgs
                {
                    Id = Id,
                    ViewModelName = _detailViewModelName
                }
                );
        }
    }
}
```

Thus I have an `ICommand` above, that upon executing, will trigger the `TestEvent` and `OpenDetailViewEvent` events, with the `TestEvent` having an integer argument, and the `OpenDetailViewEvent` having a custom class argument `OpenDetailViewEventArgs` class.

I'm testing that upon executing the command, the `Publish` method of each event is called. I use `Moq` to mock the `GetEvent` calls. This is my code:

```
using Moq;
using Prism.Events;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TrackIt.UI.Event;
using TrackIt.UI.ViewModel;
using Xunit;

namespace TrackIt.UITests.ViewModel
{
    public class NavigationItemViewModelTests
    {

        [Fact]
        public void ShouldPublishOpenFriendDetailViewEvent()
        {
            const string displayMember = "test string";
            const int id = 4;
            const string detailViewMemberName = nameof(FriendDetailViewModel); // Just take a random detail view

            var _mockedOpenDetailViewEvent = new Mock<OpenDetailViewEvent>();
            var _mockedTestEvent = new Mock<TestEvent>();
            var eventAggregatorMock = new Mock<IEventAggregator>();

            eventAggregatorMock
                .Setup(dp => dp.GetEvent<OpenDetailViewEvent>())
                .Returns(_mockedOpenDetailViewEvent.Object);
            eventAggregatorMock
                .Setup(dp => dp.GetEvent<TestEvent>())
                .Returns(_mockedTestEvent.Object);

            var _itemViewModel = new NavigationItemViewModel(id,
                 displayMember, eventAggregatorMock.Object, detailViewMemberName);

            _itemViewModel.OpenDetailViewCommand.Execute(null);

            _mockedTestEvent.Verify(e => e.Publish(id),
                                                Times.Once);
            _mockedOpenDetailViewEvent.Verify(e => e.Publish(new OpenDetailViewEventArgs { Id = id, ViewModelName = detailViewMemberName }), 
                                                Times.Once);
        }
    }
}
```

The thing is, the test passes the `Verify` for `TestEvent` event, but it fails for `OpenDetailViewEvent` with error `Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0 times`, even though I debugged and saw the event actually published. Maybe it's because I'm supplying a custom class as its argument, while `TestEvent` uses a native C# class (i.e. `int`)? How to fix this?

Comment: Use argument matcher instead since the instances can't be the same in this scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [argument matcher](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#matching-arguments) instead since the instances can't be the same object reference in this scenario.

```
// ....
_mockedOpenDetailViewEvent
    .Verify(
        _ => _.Publish(It.Is<OpenDetailViewEventArgs>(arg => arg.Id == id && arg.ViewModelName == detailViewMemberName)),
        Times.Once
    );
```

`It.Is` above is used to create a predicate to match the argument that was used to invoke the member.